# Import excel as mysql table using cakephp 2.1

Tags: database, excel, cakephp, import

Calling all cakephp gurus!!

I have hunted high and low, tied all excel readers, writers, helpers but to no avail.

I really need to import an excel file into a table, whether it creates a table or inserts into an existing one as per the excel columns iterations using cakephp 2.1

Your help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use CSV files instead of excel files(because if you try to use excel for this purpose your problem becomes more complicated as the excel file has a very complex structure than a simple csv file)
you can export excel files to csv easily using ms excel,or any other spreadsheet application

see these links

1. http://mrphp.com.au/code/importing-data-csv-cakephp
2. http://narendravaghela.com/cakephp/read-csv-file-in-cakephp/